# Escaping parentheses in Makefile rule with bash <(curl ...)

Tags: bash, curl, makefile

I want to run the infamous `bash <(curl SOME_URL)` combo in a Makefile and I'm struggling with escaping of the parenthesis. The relevant excerpt from the Makefile looks like this:

```
foo:
    docker run $(IMAGE_NAME) bash <(curl SOME_URL) \
        --some-param1 \
        --some-param2
```

Running the above via `make foo` only yields: `/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Can someone show me how to escape the parenthesis properly so I can execute the above

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is because, you are not using the `bash` shell. Your `makefile` does not use the bourne again shell (`bash`) in which process substitution is supported(`<()`), so the system executes it with `/bin/sh`. The default `/bin/sh` bourne shell is designed to run only with standard features.

Use the `SHELL := /bin/bash` in your `Makefile` to make the `bash` shell by default for all the recipes, or you could define it per recipe.

```
foo: SHELL := /bin/bash
foo:
    docker run $(IMAGE_NAME) bash <(curl SOME_URL) \
        --some-param1 \
        --some-param2
```

From [GNU `make` documentation: Choosing the Shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Choosing-the-Shell). Quoting from it to show the actual lines

> The program used as the shell is taken from the variable `SHELL`. If this variable is not set in your `makefile`, the program `/bin/sh` is used as the shell

Comment: I was not aware that the process substitution is already happening in the Makefile. I assumed it happens inside the `docker run` context, i.e. in the container running bash.

Comment: @BastianVenthur: The `make` is run in the current shell and uses the environment variable `SHELL` which by default is _not_ bash

Comment: To be clear, the process substitution is NOT happening in the makefile.  The makefile invokes a shell to run the recipe.  The shell invoked is `/bin/sh` (by default).  Basically, if you have a recipe _<recipe>_ then make runs the command `$(SHELL) -c '<recipe>'` where `$(SHELL)` is by default `/bin/sh`, and `/bin/sh` will not understand bash's process substitution.

Comment: This won't *quite* work, because the file descriptor returned by the process substitution won't be available inside the container. (But +1 because it does solve the immediate problem stated in the question.)